# All chrome pages frozen unless I use the `--no-sandbox` flag

Tags: google-chrome, centos-7

On my centos-7 laptop, unless I open chrome with the `--no-sandbox` flag, every tab gets frozen as soon as it opens. I can't even interact with the settings page.

Diagnostics thus far:

- It used to work. I don't know what changed.
- The laptop has a 16 core processor with 128 GB ram and nothing fancy running in the background, so it's not a resource limitation.
- I've signed out of my accounts, disabled sync, disabled all extensions, and run chrome in incognito
- I've completely uninstalled/reinstalled chrome, including old, current, and dev versions.
- I've deleted the `~/.cache/google-chrome` and `~/.config/google-chrome` directories
- Firefox works fine. Chromium works mostly fine, but experiences the same freeze issue for a few sites such as ebay. `--no-sandbox` fixes the issue for chromium too.
- The contents of each page are frozen (e.g. cannot click or mouse-over anything) but the browser itself seems okay. Bookmarks work, I can even scroll down the pages without problem.

Any ideas about how to make chrome work again?

Currently I use chrome with the `--no-sandbox` flag, but this results in a warning message about using an unsupported flag, every time I open chrome. If I could prevent that message, I think that would suffice as a work-around